# How to read SSH2 binary packets in Java?

Tags: java, ssh, binary, datainputstream

SSH2 session starts like:

1. Client initially connects to server on Port 22.
2. Server sends back ID string: SSH-2.0-1.0.0\r\n
3. Client sends its own identification: SSH-2.0-1.0.0\r\n(binary data)

After \r\n starts binary data

4. Server sends 2 SSH_SMSG_PUBLIC_KEY message.

I'm trying to use `DataInputStream`. As far as I can understand - I should read the first 4 bytes to know the packet length, and then read the rest of bytes, which is equal to packet length and then send server response?

PS - no need for third party SSH libraries.

Comment: Forget it. Don't try to reimplement SSH. It's already been done, several times. JSch, Ganymed SSH, ...

Comment: No no, I'm just trying to create SSH server to be able to communicate via Putty securely, the rest of SSH functions will be not implemented. I need just encrypt the data and some related SSH related functions - for example - re-keying. I would use SSL (`SSLServerSocket`), but it is impossible to use Putty in that case.